# MIDI in Java - Trying to get continuous controller data from multiple CCs but only able to get 1

Tags: java, midi

I have a Moog Theremini that outputs two sets of continuous controller data. The "pitch" antenna outputs on CC 20 and the "volume" antenna outputs on CC2.

I have no problem pulling up the track data for CC20, but after a day of reading MIDI docs and articles, can't seem to find any way to grab this other CC data on the same track. Is anyone familiar enough with this to help me out?

The output code below is what I'm trying to figure out. My intention with it is

1. Convert the last (or second to last) message on the track (there's only 1 track) to a Short Message
2. Print out the Command, Status, Controller # and Controller value
3. This is done in a loop so it continues indefinitely printing out the latest part of the track.

The below code successfully achieves the above for CC 20, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the data for CC 2. I'm not even sure why it's printing CC20 to be honest.

```
  try {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) sequencePass.getTracks()[0].get(sequencePass.getTracks()[0].size()-2).getMessage();
            System.out.println("| comm " + sm.getCommand() + "| status " + sm.getStatus()  + "| d1 (Controller#) " + sm.getData1() + "| d2 (Controller value) " + sm.getData2());
            


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("blah blah" + e);
        }
```

**Edit 1 here is the MIDI class: **

```
public MidiJunk() {
        try {
            MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo(); //looking through all of my MIDI devices
            for(int i=0;i<infos.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(infos[i].getName() + " - " + infos[i].getDescription());
            }
            System.out.println();

            MidiDevice INSTRUMENTO = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[5]); //the plugged in Theremini is here, so assigning it as a  MidiDevice
            INSTRUMENTO.open(); //opening midi device
            Sequencer sequencero = MidiSystem.getSequencer(); //default sequencer transmitter and receiver
            sequencero.open(); //open sequencer
            Transmitter transmittero = INSTRUMENTO.getTransmitter(); //linking transmitter to instrument?
            Receiver receivero = sequencero.getReceiver(); //get reciever from sequencer
            transmittero.setReceiver(receivero);
            Sequence testseq; //test sequence


            try {
                testseq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,24);
                sequencero.setSequence(testseq);
                sequencero.recordEnable(testseq.createTrack(),0);
                sequencero.setTickPosition(0);
                sequencero.startRecording();
                Timer timeo = new Timer();
                TimerTask timeoTaskeo = new displayMidiEventsOnTimer(testseq);
                timeo.schedule(timeoTaskeo,400,400);
                Scanno.nextLine();

                sequencero.stopRecording();
                MidiSystem.write(testseq,1,new File("miditest.mid"));
                System.out.println("it's done");

            } catch (Exception ene) {
                System.out.println(ene);
            }

        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println(E);

        }
    }
```

**And here is the display events class**

```
public class displayMidiEventsOnTimer extends TimerTask {
    Sequence sequencePass;

    public displayMidiEventsOnTimer(Sequence thisguy) {
        sequencePass = thisguy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) sequencePass.getTracks()[0].get(sequencePass.getTracks()[0].size()-2).getMessage();
            System.out.println("| comm " + sm.getCommand() + "| status " + sm.getStatus()  + "| d1 (Controller#) " + sm.getData1() + "| d2 (Controller value) " + sm.getData2());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use a sequence ? You should explain more your setup, and the rest of the code

Comment: My understanding of the documentation is that I need a sequence to get the track info and from there get the data from the continuous controllers. I have a ray of hope that you're implying there's a simpler way! I'm updating my post now with the full class and method info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a sequencer here, unless you want to record the relative timings between the received events.

Here is an example how to display all incoming CC messages directly in a custom Receiver.

```
...
Transmitter transmittero = INSTRUMENTO.getTransmitter(); 
Receiver receivero = new MyReceiver();   // Connect to your custom receiver
transmittero.setReceiver(receivero);
...

class MyReceiver implements Receiver
{

    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage mm, long timeStamp)
    {
        if (mm instanceof ShortMessage)
        {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) mm;
            if (sm.getCommand() == ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE)
            {
                int cc = sm.getData1();
                // Do something quick, filter ignored CCs etc.
                System.out.println("cc=" + cc);    
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get CC data from multiple CC's this way? My challenge is that I (supposedly) have two CCs sending data from the Theremini, one on CC20 and one on CC2.  Even with your method above, _I only get data from CC20_ and nothing from CC2.

Assuming the data IS submitting for both CC's, do you know of a way to pull the CC2 data?   (it's also possible the documentation from Moog is just wrong and it's not submitting at all, or perhaps a hardware problem, but I want to insure it's not just a code issue I can resolve.)

Comment: My answer lists ALL incoming Midi Controller changes (CC). If you see CC20 messages coming but not CC2 messages, then either CC2 are not sent (check the Midi settings on your Theremin), or there is something in your Midi interface which captures CC2 before (which seems unlikely to me).  You could also print all MidiMessages received (not only CC ShortMessages) to get the full picture. Use toString() from https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab-X/blob/master/Midi/src/org/jjazz/midi/api/MidiUtilities.java to make the output readable, or use a Midi dump tool llike MidiOX.

Comment: Right on, thanks for much for the help @jjazzboss !